# scanf не распознаёт спецификатор «%llu»

Tags: c, codeblocks

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, о чем компилятор на ровном месте предупреждает в следующем коде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> - warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format
> - warning: too many arguments for format

1. Почему ему не нравится спецификатор считывания `%llu` для `unsigned long long`?
2. О каком неизвестном символе `l` идет речь?
3. Каких аргументов слишком много?

Версия компилятора: the GCC/G++ compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 5.1.0, 32 bit, SJLJ).

Comment: Что-то вы недоговариваете...Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ваш код вполне нормально компилируется тут, например: https://ideone.com/FD3oou

Comment: Привел пример в скриншоте.

Comment: [How do you printf an unsigned long long int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844/how-do-you-printf-an-unsigned-long-long-intthe-format-specifier-for-unsigned-lo)

Comment: такую ошибку можно получить, если второй l является на самом деле единицей (но код то Вы не привели, @Максим). И версию компилятора лучше указать, а то может там 4.6-4.8, которые по умолчанию хотят С90 (шизофренник - это не версия компилятора)

Comment: Вторая l точно не является единицей. Версия компилятора: the GCC/G++ compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 5.1.0, 32 bit, SJLJ), по крайней мере так написано в описании при скачивании Code::Blocks 17.12

Comment: может там любой другой символ, похожий на l.

Comment: eanmos, фишка в том, что программа работает корректно, ошибок нет, scanf()/printf() адекватно воспринимают спецификатор формата %llu, но вот предупреждения есть. И я не понимаю, что не так.

Comment: Там нет любого другого символа. Это абсолютно точно, на все 100%

Comment: А попробуйте-ка скобки убрать в `#define`. Вроде и ни при чем, но я с вашим компилятором не знаком, вдруг он со странностями... А в вашем исходном вопросе было написано `#define SF "%llu"` - без скобок. Вот так и попробуйте...

Comment: @Максим, сдаётся мне, что ты компилируешь код для с++ (причём с++03), вот он и ругается. Вместо скриншота, скопируй в вопрос код и вывод из окна «Build.log»... и да, для уверенности в версии лучше запусти вручную из консоли `\path\to\mingw-*gcc --version`. Вывод также сюда.

Comment: Дело не в скобках в define. Скобки как раз и воткнул, чтобы уж прям точно при раскрытии макроконстанты не возникло никаких неожиданностей. Компилирую я в режиме C99, уже много раз проверял, но возможно у меня просто возникла какая-то внутренняя ошибка в самой IDE, надо попробовать ее переустановить.

Comment: воспроизвел эту ошибку. Оно только на TDM-GCC воспроизводится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это бага компилятора TDM-GCC. Или не бага, а особенность. [Пост на форуме](https://sourceforge.net/p/tdm-gcc/bugs/62/), где пишут, что такое поведение "by design".

Что делать? смирится или сменить компилятор.